# How to create REST API in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, oauth

i'm new to Magento 2, i am assigned to create a HTML search form which take input as a CustomerID and return the Customer info associated with that CustomerID, using oAuth and REST API.  I have no idea where I should begin, or which documents I should take, please give me an advice !

Comment: You should start at https://www.google.com/#q=Magento2+documentation+rest+api

Answer (score 1):

Two high-level steps should be completed to create new REST API in Magento:

1. Create new [service](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-contracts.html)
2. [Configure webapi.xml](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-to-web-service.html) to expose this service as REST API

Then your service can be called as described [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html)